# Need admin approval in Azure Ad

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory

I have configured AAD login for application and configured user groups for that. Few of the users in the groups are able to login and few of the users are unable to login. For few users it is asking for admin approval.

[image]

[image]

Below permissions are added
[image]

Even I have added the particular users to the application. But no luck. May be I am missing some configurations.

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: What is the difference between these few users who cannot log in and other users who can log in?

Comment: Hi @carl, No difference between users

Comment: While login for the first time azure asks for basic permission and user should grant those. I am suspecting that, for the users who are able to login they have granted the permissions but the few other users not granted permissions. How can I check this?

Comment: You try the following two methods: 1. Configure [user consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-user-consent?tabs=azure-portal#user-consent-settings). https://i.stack.imgur.com/vb6qm.png  2. The configuration [administrator consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/grant-admin-consent#grant-admin-consent-in-app-registrations). https://i.stack.imgur.com/etM2w.png

Comment: Already configured as per step 1 above

Comment: Still unable to log in?

Comment: What is your login URL?

Comment: @Boss, did you ever get this figured out?  I'm having same issue.  I'm able to login but other users are getting the "need admin approval" error.

Comment: @KatieP - I am also facing the same issue .few users in the group are able to login and few are not able to . Any leads on the issue would help thanks

Answer (score 0):

Move comment to answer:

I guess you may have permissions that have not been approved by the administrator, or you may not have granted consent to users. Try to follow the steps below:

- Grant the administrator consent for the tenant's permissions. You need to execute the administrator's consent url in the browser, and then use the global administrator to log in and authorize:

  `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/v2.0/adminconsent? client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e &state=12345 &redirect_uri=http://localhost/myapp/permissions &scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`
- Configure [user consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-user-consent?tabs=azure-portal#user-consent-settings):
  [image]
- Ensure that your application and users are in the same tenant.

  `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`